# Mixing materials using textures in nodes

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I am doing a test for mixing three materials using black-and-white image in nodes.

What I want basically is something like this -

[image]

It is a cube object. And on the white portion the material colour is yellow and in black portion the material color is red and in blue portion the material color is Green.

So what I did is I opened up GIMP and made two separate black-and-white image. Like these -

Map1

[image]

Map2

[image]

And then set-up the nodes this way -

[image]

But I am not getting the desired result. What is wrong with this? And how to fix it?

Do we mix various materials this way for complex meshes and material mixing patterns? What is the best way to achieve this?

I am adding the blend file for further clarification:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one difuse shader and the rest is combining colors using the existing masks.

The result of one RGB mix is concatenated to another RGB mix and those become the color for the shader.

[image]

(Click on the images to expand to full screen)

If you must use shaders then the masks are used in a similar way to concatenate the mixes one over the other.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it. For experiment, I was trying to draw a bump map. Like this. The green portion should be swollen. So I used a blank image and used it in image texture node and fed it to a bump node and then the output of the bump node into normal input of the green diffusion shader node. That is fine. But I can't draw it properly. It is sometimes getting swollen. Sometime not. Sometime if i zoom out it is getting swollen. But if i zoom in, it is not working.

Comment: I have no idea of what you are trying to do. If you have unrelated questions use a new post.