# How to mix three different shaders on the same material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

So I came across some difficulties with the "Mix shader" node in cycles. I have 3 textures on a label: gold, paper and rough black letters.

[image]

How can I mix these effects? I can make 2 textures work together, but not the 3rd one.
Here's the node graph.

[image]

Here's the reference.
[image]

Comment: Hello~
I eddited the post and added a ref which is my expected result!
Thanks :)

Comment: How can I link them..? Sorry for the dumb question :(

Comment: I made a google drive folder for convinience..I hope it's ok.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W-gy4t5j1CYeYb3BY5_-u182jqio_kdh?usp=sharing


There is the scene and textures that I used.

Comment: Use the textures as masks to mix different shaders. All explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109464/mixing-materials-using-textures-in-nodes/109773#109773

Comment: Thank you so much! That's very useful.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208639 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95522 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5069

Answer (score 10):

The textures all have an Alpha channel perfectly prepared for a mask.
So you only need two mix nodes.

[image]
[image]

But I'd recommend making four different textures instead - *Color, Roughness, Metalness* and *Bump*. Then you just plug them all into one Principled BSDF shader, have more control and an easier life :).